# When Partitioner runs in Map Reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As per my understanding, mapper runs first followed by partitioner(if any) followed by Reducer. But if we use Partitioner class, I am not sure when Sorting and Shuffling phase runs?

Comment: Map -> Partitioner -> Sort -> Shuffle -> Sort -> Reduce

https://0x0fff.com/hadoop-mapreduce-comprehensive-description/

Answer (score 0):

A CLOSER LOOK

Below diagram explain the complete details.

From this diagram, you can see where the mapper and reducer components of the Word Count application fit in, and how it achieves its objective. We will now examine this system in a bit closer detail.
mapreduce-flow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle and Sort phase will always execute(across the mappers and reducers nodes).

The hierarchy of the different phase in MapReduce as below:

**Map --> Partition --> Combiner(optional) --> Shuffle and Sort --> Reduce.**

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Data sorting runs on the reducers, shuffling/sorting runs **before** the reducer (always) and **after** the map/combiner(if any)/partitioner(if any).

The long answer is that into a MapReduce job there are 4 main players:
**Mapper**, **Combiner**, **Partitioner**, **Reducer**. All these are classes you can actually implement by your own.

Let's take the famous word count program, and let's assume the split where we are working contains:

```
pippo, pluto, pippo, pippo, paperino, pluto, paperone, paperino, paperino
```

and each word is record.

**Mapper**

Each mapper runs over a subset of your file, its task is to read each record from the split and assign a key to each record which will output.
Mapper will store intermediate result on disk ( local disk ).

The intermediate output from this stage will be

```
pippo,1 
pluto,1
pippo,1
pippo,1
peperino,1
pluto,1
paperone,1
paperino,1
paperino,1
```

At this will be stored on the local disk of the node which runs the mapper.

**Combiner**

It's a mini-reducer and can aggregate data. It can also run joins, so called map-join. This object helps to save bandwidth into the cluster because it aggregates data on the local node.

The output from the combiner, which is still part of the mapper phase, will be:

```
pippo,3
pluto,2
paperino,3
paperone,1
```

Of course here are the data from ONE node. Now we have to send the data to the reducers in order to get the global result. Which reducer will process the record depends on the partitioner.

**Partitioner**

It's task is to spread the data across all the available reducers. This object will read the output from the combiner and will select the reducer which will process the key.

In this example we have two reducers and we use the following rule:

```
all the pippo goes to reducer 1
all the pluto goes to reducer 2
all the paperino goes to reducer 2 
all the paperone goes to reducer 1
```

so all the nodes will send records which have the key pippo to the same reducer(1), all the nodes will send the records which have the key pluto to the same reducer (2) and so on...

***Here is where the data get shuffled/sorted*** and, since the combiner already reduced the data locally, this node has to send only 4 record instead of 9.

**Reducer**

This object is able to aggregate the data from each node and it's also able to sort the data.